# What is The Atom working on with Green Arrow In the beginning of S01e01 of Legends of Tomorrow

Tags: dc, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

I know they infiltrated Hive, but what was that thing he was in?  Do we see this specific piece of plot in The Green Arrow episodes?